# Como montar uma estrutura JSON?

Tags: php, mysql, json, web-service

Tenho o seguinte JSON:

```
{
"status": true,
"msg": "",
"frete": [
    {
        "Transportadora": "Correios",
        "Tempo": "16",
        "Msg": "",
        "Codigo": "04510",
        "Servico": "PAC",
        "Valor": "131.30"
    },
    {
        "Transportadora": "Correios",
        "Tempo": "10",
        "Msg": "",
        "Codigo": "04014",
        "Servico": "Sedex",
        "Valor": "239.80"
    }
],
"embalagem": "60x32x28,7000"
}
```

Como eu faço pra montar esse json em PHP?

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
function calculaFrete($cod_servico = null, $cep_origem, $cep_destino, $peso, $altura = '2', $largura = '11', $comprimento = '16', $valor_declarado = '0.50') {
$parametros = array();
$parametros['nCdEmpresa'] = '';
$parametros['sDsSenha'] = '';
$parametros['sCepOrigem'] = $cep_origem;
$parametros['sCepDestino'] = $cep_destino;
$parametros['nVlPeso'] = $peso;
$parametros['nCdFormato'] = '1';
$parametros['nVlComprimento'] = $comprimento;
$parametros['nVlAltura'] = $altura;
$parametros['nVlLargura'] = $largura;
$parametros['nVlDiametro'] = '0';
$parametros['sCdMaoPropria'] = 's';
$parametros['nVlValorDeclarado'] = $valor_declarado;
$parametros['sCdAvisoRecebimento'] = 'n';
$parametros['StrRetorno'] = 'xml';
$parametros['nCdServico'] = '04014,04510';
$parametros = http_build_query($parametros);
$url = 'http://ws.correios.com.br/calculador/CalcPrecoPrazo.aspx';
$curl = curl_init($url . '?' . $parametros);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$dados = curl_exec($curl);
$dados = simplexml_load_string($dados);

$json = array();
$json['status'] = true;
$json['msg'] = '';

foreach ($dados->cServico as $linhas) {

    if ($linhas->Erro == 0) {
        if ($linhas->Codigo == '04510'):
            $servico = 'PAC';
        elseif ($linhas->Codigo == '04014'):
            $servico = 'SEDEX';
        endif;

        $json['frete']['Transportadora'] = 'Correios';
        $json['frete']['Tempo'] = $linhas->PrazoEntrega;
        $json['frete']['Msg'] = '';
        $json['frete']['Codigo'] = $linhas->Codigo;
        $json['frete']['Servico'] = $servico;
        $json['frete']['Valor'] = $linhas->Valor;
    } else {
        echo $linhas->MsgErro;
    }
}
$json['embalagem'] = "60x32x28,7000";
echo json_encode($json);
}

calculaFrete(null, '40760170', '40760210', 7.000, 28, 32, 60, 35);
```

Esse PHP me retorna isso, totalmente diferente:

```
{"status":true,"msg":"","frete":{"Transportadora":"Correios","Tempo":{"0":"10"},"Msg":"","Codigo":{"0":"04510"},"Servico":"PAC","Valor":{"0":"35,85"}},"embalagem":"60x32x28,7000"}
```

Comment: Ambos os json são válidos, mas de RFC diferente. Qual o problema?

Comment: por exemplo: nao deu o loop, do pac e sedex e nos parametros tempo codigo, aparece o 0, e nao pode ficar assim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi o problema fazendo dessa forma:

```
foreach ($dados->cServico as $linhas) {
    $linhas = (array) $linhas;
    if ($linhas['Erro'] == 0) {
        if ($linhas['Codigo'] == '04510'):
            $servico = 'PAC';
        elseif ($linhas['Codigo'] == '04014'):
            $servico = 'SEDEX';
        endif;

        $array[] = ['Transportadora' => 'Correios',
            'Tempo' => $linhas['PrazoEntrega'],
            'Msg' => '',
            'Codigo' => $linhas['Codigo'],
            'Servico' => $servico,
            'Valor' => $linhas['Valor']];
    } else {
        echo $linhas['MsgErro'];
    }
}
$json['frete'] = $array;
$json['embalagem'] = "60x32x28,7000";
echo json_encode($json, true);
```

Answer (score -2):

Você está adicionando um objeto dentro do array, o [php](/questions/tagged/php) está incluindo o ponteiro na atribuição do seu array, utilize o cast de objeto para array nas linhas que você está atribuindo ao array `$json['frete]`.

Segue o exemplo:

```
$json['frete']['Transportadora'] = 'Correios';
$json['frete']['Tempo'] = (array) $linhas->PrazoEntrega;
$json['frete']['Msg'] = '';
$json['frete']['Codigo'] = (array) $linhas->Codigo;
$json['frete']['Servico'] = $servico;
$json['frete']['Valor'] = (array) $linhas->Valor;
```

Veja se isso te ajuda.

Comment: sim, estou utilizando json_encode

Comment: Pablo, considere comentar na própria pergunta para tirar suas dúvidas, não vejo isso como resposta.

Comment: Preciso do loop dentro do array frete, eu realmente esqueci como faz esse loop, e a resposta, não ajuda no que eu quero fazer.

Comment: faça cast na atribuição $json['frete']['?']